# C Loop until the condition is met problem

Tags: c, loops

I want to write a loop that runs until the user enters a number greater than 10, but I have to do something wrong because it creates an infinite loop.

```
int main()
{
    int a;
    printf("Enter 'a' value (min 10): ");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    for(int i=0;a<10;i++){
        printf("Enter value>10");
        i++;
        printf("%d",&a);
    }
    printf("Result:%d",a+a-2+a-4+a-6+a-8+a-10);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know i Can write it using if() and then refer to main (), but using loops is better.

Comment: I suggest you do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) of your code. Or indeed step through it in an actual debugger.

Comment: Also, a `while` loop might ave been better here, what's the use of `i` inside the loop?

Comment: Replace `printf` for `a` in the loop with `scanf`

Comment: What's the use of `6*a-30` as a result? :-)

Comment: Do not edit questions so as to invalidate answers - rolled back:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mix an index that does not make sense. Also you print the memory address of variable instead of its value, not sure it is what you wanted?
Code partially corrected (because I don't know what is your ultimate goal):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a;

    do {
        printf("Enter 'a' value (min 10): ");
        scanf("%d",&a);
        printf("\na: %d\n",a);
    } while (a <= 10);
    printf("Result:%d\n",a+a-2+a-4+a-6+a-8+a-10);
    return 0;
}
```

ps: \n is line return and added do while which is what you want when you want to execute a loop at least once.

Comment: Thanks,that's worked, I left printf by accident, sorry

Comment: Wouldn't a `do ... while ` loop be better?

Comment: I tried to keep it the closer to the author's logic. Else I would also have questioned the utility of the very last printf

Comment: @Taco If it worked fine please select it as the answer for your question ;)

Comment: Are you sure about `printf("%d",&a);`? `%d` expects an `int`, but `&a` is an `int*`.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at your for-loop: you let `i` start at zero, you continue until `a` is not smaller than ten anymore, but it's not the value of `a` you need to check, it's the one of `i`.

In top of that, you are doing a `i++` within your for-loop, while this is already covered in the definition of the for-loop.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the code that you are looking for: See comments

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{

int a, ok = 0, end_of_input = 0;

do {

   printf("Please input an integer value (min. 10): ");
   fflush(stdout); // So the user can see the above line!
   switch(scanf("%d",&a)) {
   case EOF: // End of input - Give up!
     end_of_input = 1;
     break;
   case 1: // Got a number - Check it!
     if (a < 10) 
     {
       ok = 1;
     } else {
       printf("%d - Not appropriate input. Please try again.\n\n",a);
     }
     break;
   default: // Summat else - "eat" the input to the next line
      scanf("%*[^\n]\n"); // "eats" the rest of the line in the buffer w/o assignment
      break;
    }
  } while (end_of_input == 0 || ok == 0);
  if (ok) { // User entered a valid number
     printf("Got a that is smaller than ten %d\n", d);
  } else { // We have ran out of input
     printf("See you want to leave us :-(\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve but one problem that I found in your logic is you prompting user for input outside the loop. So whenever you enter number less than 10 it always goes in infinite iteration.

Try following code, with scanf inside loop

```
int main()
{
    int a;
    printf("Enter 'a' value (min 10): ");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    int i=0;
    for(;a<10;){
        printf("Enter value>10");
        scanf("%d",&a);
        printf("%d",a);
        i++;
    }
    printf("Result:%d",a+a-2+a-4+a-6+a-8+a-10);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for(int i=0;a<10;i++)` looks odd, you never use `i`, so you can remove it: `for (;a<10;)`, which is the same as `while (a<10)`. `printf("%d",&a);` should be `printf("%d", a);`

Comment: That's correct in c you use initialization outside the loop. I just helped him to correct the logic. Edited my answer